# Reference for weak*-semigroup

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, textbook-recommendation, semigroups-of-operators

Let $X$ a dual Banach space (there exists a Banach space $Y$ such that $X=Y'$). 
A weak* semigroup on $X$ is a semigroup $(T_t)_{\geq 0}$ on $X$ such that, for all $x\in X$, we have $T_tx\to x$ in the weak* topology when $t\to 0^+$.

I know a lot of books about $C_0$-semigroups but not about weak* semigroups.

> Do you know a good place to read about weak* semigroups and their generators? A book would be perfect.

Comment: In your first line, presumably you mean convergence in w*-topology as $t$ tends to 0, for each $x$?

Comment: Even that wouldn't make sense, unless $X$ is the dual of something.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.
However, I forgot a part of the statement. I am sorry. 

Comment: If the $T_t$ are all weak$^*$ continuous, you are just looking at the dual semigroup to a strongly continuous semigroup on the predual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Echoing the remark of @Bill Johnson, one possibility is [van Neerven's book](http://books.google.hu/books/about/The_adjoint_of_a_semigroup_of_linear_ope.html?id=9jbvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) on adjoint semigroups.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite follow your notation, but I'll answer what I think you might be asking.

A $C_0$ or *strongly continuous* semigroup of operators $T_t$ on a Banach space $X$ is one such that $T_t x \to x$ in norm as $t \to 0$, i.e. $||T_t x - x||_X \to 0$.  In other words, $T_t \to I$ in the strong operator topology.

A *weakly continuous* semigroup $T_t$ has $T_t x \to x$ weakly as $t \to 0$, i.e. $f(T_t x) \to f(x)$ for each $f \in X^*$.  In other words, $T_t \to I$ in the weak operator topology.

In fact, these two conditions are equivalent.  This appears as Theorem 1.6 of K.-J. Engel and R. Nagel, *A Short Course on Operator Semigroups*.

So this is why you never hear anyone talking about weakly continuous semigroups.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I forgot a part of the statement. I am sorry.